# What is the label appears in Setting->apps->tap on app -> different sizes of app?

Tags: settings, storage

for example, Under the storage label - App, USB storage app, Data, SD card. How these size was handled by the Android system ?

I have attached a screen shot. The flickOpic app is developed by me. the `flickOpic.apk` size is 3.00 MB.

**Question:** How this app becomes total 66.87 MB? What kinds of code stored in app, USB Storage app, Data, SD card? What is the system file/folder path for app, USB Storage app, Data, SD card?

[image: this is screen shot of flickOpic app]

My device: Sony Ericsson Arc S LT18i, OS: android 4.0.3

Comment: Could you mention your device model and Android version, and also include a screenshot? Different device may have different Setting configuration.

Comment: Thanks for comment,
I have updated question, Now are u clear about my question ?

Comment: Do you have a link to that app which includes an app description? Understanding what the app does allows for a more precise answer (especially for the USB storage and SD card part).

Comment: google Play Store link (or you can search flickOpic in play store):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flickopic.flickr.wallpaper